# Can NaOH and NaH2PO2 exist together in aqueous solution?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base

> Can $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{NaH2PO2}$ exist together in aqueous solution?

My textbook denies it, but I feel that since $\ce{NaH2PO2}$ is acidic, it should react with $\ce{NaOH}$, because in my textbook it is written that salts of even weak acids can react with a strong Base (*e.g.*, $\ce{NaHCO3}$ is mentioned to react with $\ce{NaOH}$).

Comment: $\ce{NaH2PO2}$ is not acidic and it is a common catch for less observant students. ( Or rather has extremely low, not mentioned acidity.), as the remaining hydrogens of [hypophosphorous acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypophosphorous_acid) are bound directly to phosphorus.( $\ce{HO-PH2=O}$ ). Similarly, only 2 of 3 hydrogen atoms of phosphorous acid $\ce{H3PO3}$  are acidic.

Comment: Neither of substances really exists in aqueous solution. They're both fairly dissociated into ions.

Comment: Can you give the title of your textbook, and paraphrase a few lines?

Comment: @Karl , Its the study material provided by my coaching classes for IIT JEE prep. You won't really need to know the name.

Comment: Well, I can only advise you to take everything coming out of the IIT-JEE complex with the utmost caution. Just my opinion, based on the purely anecdotal evidence of questions I have seen here on chem.SE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Your question:** Can $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{NaH2PO2}$ exist together in aqueous solution?

I assume what you meant is your *textbook* is saying when two separate solutions of $\ce{NaOH}$ and $\ce{NaH2PO2}$ are combined, there should be no reaction. If that is what you meant "exist together," then your textbook is correct because there won't be an acid-base reaction since $\ce{NaH2PO2}$ has no "acidic hydrogen" contrast to $\ce{NaH2PO4}$ and $\ce{Na2HPO4}$ as Poutnik mentioned in his comment (more descriptive presentation would be $\ce{Na^+^-OP(=O)H2}$). The following diagram summerizes this point:

[image: Phoshates and carbonates]

As diagram shows $\ce{NaH2PO2}$ (sodium hypophosphite) does not have any acidic protons to react with strong bases like $\ce{NaOH}$. The two hydrogens in $\ce{NaH2PO2}$  have attach ed to phosphorous atom in covalent bonds. And also showing is sodium bicarbonate, which has one acidic proton to react with $\ce{NaOH}$.